# Electron (Atom shell) native code: window focus

Tags: c++, fingerprint, electron

I have created a native C++ add-on for the [WinBioCaptureSample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I've tested it, and it works when running the native code separately in a command window (using node ./test.js). However, when I try to run it in my electron app, the app blocks.

I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that the WinBioCaptureSample function requires window focus (if I pass something else, all works fine). However, it seems that in the Electron app, there never is window focus (due to the fact that it is encapsulated maybe?). It's a long shot, but has anybody already run into same problem, or something similar?

A possible solution would be to open a separate command window, but this would be ugly and in case the user closes this window, the problem would persist.

Comment: Native bindings should be compiled against electron (and not node) headers. Have you already done that?

Comment: Hi, i provided an answer to my own question but it seems to have been deleted. Anyway the compiling was not an issue, i just needed the window focus.

Comment: you may want to add it to the question for the future ref :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [WinBioAcquireFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee221189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does the job. You can call this method like so

```
WinBioAcquireFocus();
```

Make sure your application has local system privileges, so that it will always be able to capture a sample, even if it has been opened in the background. WinBioReleaseFocus() must be called to release focus.